# How do I know that a plot of a function is correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

This might seem like a weirdly elementary question - and it is certainly meant to be a fundamental one, rather than a practical one (that is you are not supposed to just plug it into a graphing software to verify it). How do I know that a graph on the cartesian plane is indeed the correct one?

For instance, consider the equation: $y = x^3 + 5$. And consider a picture which purports to be its graphical representation (this one is generated by a computer so it happens to be correct):
[cube plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfkvS.png)

I think for equations beyond straights lines and conic sections, the only way to verify if the graph is indeed correct is by checking it for all possible points, which isn't actually feasible. Sure, one could propose that by taking the derivative, you can check the function is increasing/decreasing etc., and similar claims can be made in regard to its concavity by using the second derivative. But is that information sufficient to determine what the representation of a graph would be, visually?

Comment: I use a programmable calculator and plot enough points to draw it myself. When necessary, I prove that certain features hold, for example if it appears a (function) is positive over an interval. Anyway, I encourage people to draw things themselves, not just stare at computer plots.

Comment: If the function isn't horrific, consider making a short table of ordered pairs and playing 'connect-the-dots'. If this matches what a computer software program gives you, you can feel more confident its not giving you baloney.

Comment: I'm guessing the question concerns the authenticity of graphs plotted by a computer, too.

Comment: How would you visually distinguish $y=x$ from $y=x+\varepsilon$ for a tiny positive $\varepsilon$, e.g. such that the distance between the two graphs plotted with some infinitely precise printer is less than the wavelength of visible spectra of light?

Comment: Plots can be deceiving ... omitting point discontinuities ("holes"), missing (or misrepresenting) asymptotes, etc. A function grapher typically samples $x$-values and plots the calculated $y$s; if interesting/catastrophic stuff happens between the sampled $x$s, you won't see it. "Implicit" plots are worse: When graphing, say, $x^3+y^3+xy=15$, a grapher samples pts in the plane, marking those whose coords satisfy the eqn (to reasonable approximation); this can omit isolated pts and other details. One hopes to gain a certain intuition about how eqns (mis)behave, to know when to be skeptical.